# Visual Web Developer - ASP.NET Web Application Administration PROBLEM

Tags: visual-studio, visual-web-developer, createuserwizard

Was wondering if somebody could please help me solve this.

I've follwed all steps correctly, but when I go to create a new user, it keeps saying "Password length minimum: 7. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 1."

I have tried about 20 different combinations of passwords and it just keeps saying the exact same thing and won't let me create a new user.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: What passwords have you tried?  Have you used a special character like !, @, etc.

Comment: Try Admin$11 for your password

Comment: sorry about the delay i went shopping lol. i have tried JYIops47fx1q and lots of different variations

Comment: thank you @David Stratton, am trying it now.

Comment: @Andy White - No, I haven't tried any special characters. I usually just assume they're not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pulling in the membership API security settings store in the database configuration; it's requiring at least one non alpha numeric character, so are you trying to add in _@^&%$, etc. characters too?  To test this out, you can try to edit the configuration file, and change some of those settings.

There is a minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters that controls the non alpha characters, which you can set to zero to test.  More information on the configuration is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx